# Compilie ImGui with FreeType, without DLL's

Tags: c++, dll, exe, freetype, imgui

I have an ImGui project that uses FreeType.
I want to compile a project without libraries that appear after installing freetype.

```
#define IMGUI_ENABLE_FREETYPE
```

After define i have 4 libraries besides the main executable:

```
bz2.dll
freetype.dll
libpng16.dll
zlib1.dll
```

Comment: Possibly using vcpkg and the static option. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/

Comment: You are looking for static linking.